# Display an image in the navbar which is hidden when navbar is collapsed

Tags: css, asp.net, image, navbar

I am very new to web development.  I am building a page using ASP.Net based on the Visual Studio 2013 template which incorporates bootstrap css.  The Site Master has the standard navbar setup incorprating the asp:Login control.  The navbar collapses when the screen resizes (which I like) .  I have added 2 images to the navbar.  One at the left end and one at the right end of the navbar.  The right hand image shows to the right of the "Login/Register" menu options.  This is all working and displaying as I would like however when the window size is reduced below the collapse threshold and the navbar adjusts from being horizontal to a vertical menu, the image I have at the right hand end gets included in the dropdown vertical menu and appears above the Login/Register options.  I would like the image at the right hand end to simply be hidden when the navbar collapses.

Code

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-header" runat="server" href="http://example.com.au" target="_blank">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="55px"
                        ImageUrl="~/Images/logo.png" ImageAlign="Middle" BorderWidth="0px" BackColor="#033C73" EnableTheming="False" />
                </a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/PreAlerts_View" id="preAlertsLink">PreAlerts</a></li>

                </ul>

                <a class="navbar-header navbar-right navbar-form" runat="server" href="~/">
                    <asp:Image ID="RightLogo" runat="server" Height="55px"
                        ImageUrl="~/Images/logo_med.png" ImageAlign="Middle"
                        BorderWidth="0px" BackColor="White" EnableTheming="False" />
                </a>

                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a id="registerLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a id="loginLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a runat="server" class="username" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello,
                                    <asp:LoginName runat="server" CssClass="username" />
                                    !
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>

                </asp:LoginView>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a runat="server" id="adminLink" href="~/Account/AdminPage" visible="false">Admin</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `media query` for this. So something

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
#RightLogo {
display: none;
}
}
```